# Android camera auto-focus stops working after some time

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

In my Android app, the focus mode is set to `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE.`. Here is some relevant code:

```
private Camera.AutoFocusCallback _cbAutoFocus = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

    private int _count = 0;
    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        if (success) {
            _count++;
            if ((_count % 500) == 0) {
                Log.d("MyCam Focus", Integer.toString(_count));
            }
            _camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        }
        _camera.autoFocus(_cbAutoFocus);
    }
};

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    try {
        if (this._camera != null) {
            this._camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            this._camera.startPreview();
            this._camera.autoFocus(this._cbAutoFocus);
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Camera Surface change", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As I move the camera over some printed text, the camera seems to auto-focus properly for some time. However, after a while, it stops focusing and I don't get success as true in my `onAutoFocus` code. Wondering if anyone has any insights. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE or FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO do not always work even if supported by the device. It seems it is better to use FOCUS_MODE_AUTO and manually call `autofocus()` each time the focus is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this in the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)?:

> Applications can call autoFocus(AutoFocusCallback) in this mode. If
>   the autofocus is in the middle of scanning, the focus callback will
>   return when it completes. If the autofocus is not scanning, the focus
>   callback will immediately return with a boolean that indicates whether
>   the focus is sharp or not. The apps can then decide if they want to
>   take a picture immediately or to change the focus mode to auto, and
>   run a full autofocus cycle. **The focus position is locked after
>   autoFocus call.** If applications want to resume the continuous focus,
>   cancelAutoFocus must be called. Restarting the preview will not resume
>   the continuous autofocus. To stop continuous focus, applications
>   should change the focus mode to other modes.

It seems that when the [`autoFocus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback)) method is called, the auto-focus is locked. Call [`cancelAutoFocus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#cancelAutoFocus()) resume auto-focus.

In the onAutoFocus, at the end of the method (regardless of success), `autoFocus` is called, which will focus then lock the focus regardless of any further movement of the camera. Is this intentional?

Comment: If I don't call autofocus() again, my callback is never invoked after the first run.